# What is the longest ban ever imposed in cricket?

Tags: cricket, trivia

What is the longest ban ever imposed in cricket (excluding life bans)? Please provide the offence and the duration of the ban.

Comment: By the longest suspension, you mean for lifetime or in terms of years?

Comment: Excluding life bans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Excluding life bans

**[Gulam Bodi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulam_Bodi) holds the record for longest suspension of 20 years**. He was banned in 2012 by CSA for match fixing scandal.

[Source](http://tsmsportz.com/cricket/longest-banned-cricketers/)

From [ESPN Cricinfo article](http://www.espncricinfo.com/southafrica/content/story/965455.html),

> Cricket South Africa has banned Gulam Bodi for 20 years from participating in any international or domestic match, or any cricket activity other than anti-corruption programs after he admitted to contriving or attempting to fix matches during the 2015 Ram Slam T20 series.